# QT and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt

Can any one provide me with a step by step how-to for getting QT to work in VS 2010?

I have:

- Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate
- Windows 7 Enterprise.
- qt-sdk-win-opensource-2010.05
- qt-vs-addin-1.1.7

I tried executing this from Visual Studio command prompt:

```
configure.exe -platform win32-msvc2008 -no-webkit -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -no-script -no-scripttools -no-multimedia -no-qt3support -fast
```

Then:

```
nmake
```

I installed the add in, but when I go to the QT menu and try to add a build, it says "your build was built using MingW"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the version of Qt already compiled for Visual Studio 2008 (latest version from [here](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008)). It should work with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Linking with lib files compiled with a prior version of the C++ runtime is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Qt V4.8.0 contains prebuilt binaries for Visual Studio 2010 so you don't need to build manually anymore:
http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2010

Answer (score 1):

The new Qt 4.7 adds support for a `win32-msvc2010` qmake makespec.

The SDK compiled for MSVS2008 should work fine though...

Answer (score 0):

The Qt SDK you have downloaded (qt-sdk-win-opensource-2010.05) does not yet support VS 2010.
It doesn't detect a Visual Studio version it knows about and that's why it installs the MinGW build of Qt. Unfortunately this cannot be used with the Qt VS Add-in.

AFAIK full VS 2010 support will be added when Qt 4.8 is released.